# If $x^2+mx+n=0, m,n \in \mathbb Z$ and the only possible $x$ is $-3$, then what is $m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Here's what I did:

$$(-3)^2 + (-3)m + n = 0$$
$$n-3m+9 = 0$$

All answer choices are integers; substituting all values also give integer values for $n$. I do not know how to proceed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The ONLY possible value for $x$ is $-3$. This means that $-3$ is a zero of multiplicity 2. So $x^2+mx+n=(x+3)^2$. Now you have $x^2+mx+n=(x+3)^2=x^2+6x+9$. So $m=6$, i.e., the answer is C.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions to quadratics come in complex conjugate pairs. Therefore this quadratic has only one real root and no complex ones. This implies the quadratic is $(x+3)^2$ and the answer is 6.